# Ordering nodes which are given as parameter in newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I order nodes which are given to a command?

Lets say I have a tree and some children.
Now I want to create a tikzpicture visualizing that.

```
                ---------
                | tree  |
                ---------

---------       ---------       ---------
| child |       | child |       | child |
---------       ---------       ---------
```

A priori a tree should be able to have `n` children.
This structure should be reusable in my document, therefore I want to create a macro which does that for me. I imagine something like this:

```
\tree{
    \node{child 1},
    \node{child 2},
    ...
}
```

I thought about creating a command tree and child:

```
\newcommand{\tree}[2]{
    %... the tree
    \foreach \x in #1 { %\x are the given node
        \x; %Print the nodes
    }
}
```

How can I now use the positioning package to place the children correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also with `tikz` using the `trees` library, is not so difficult syntax and possible to make a command using the `foreach` statement. Note that the `foreach` must go after calling `child` or else all commands issued by `foreach` will be enclosed in braces resulting in a tree with no branches (thank's to [Mark Wibrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334581/ordering-nodes-which-are-given-as-parameter-in-newcommand/334590?noredirect=1#comment820364_334590) for the tip).

The command syntax is:

```
\mytree[<coordinate>]{<main name>}{<comma separated list of children names>};
```

The optional Argument places the `<main name>` tree node in `<coordinate>` and the tree children follow the comma separated list order from left to right. The MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\newcommand{\mytree}[3][(0,0)]{\node at #1 {#2} [edge from parent/.style={draw=none}] child foreach \child in {#3} {node {\child}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=draw]
\mytree{Tree}{Child1, Child2, Child3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output with trees library]

Comment: How can I make commands with this?

Comment: I am especially interested in passing the node in the child to a new command

Comment: I was trying to make a `cmd` with a `foreach` statement but seems that the `foreach` adds begin and end groups `{}` in between the `child {node{<txt>}}` making the tree grow only in the main branch... I'll see if it's possible with `\pgfkeys`

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos how about if you use the `child foreach` syntax (note no backslash before `foreach`: `\node at (0,0) {Tree} [edge from parent/.style={draw=none}] child 
foreach \i in {1, 2, 3} {node {Child \i}};`

Comment: Yes, that is perfect @MarkWibrow, I'm amazed on how I did not see that before... I was trying to repeat `child{node{\child}` blindly. Do you wish to make your own answer?

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos no, it's basically your answer (at least the intent) but with modified syntax

Comment: @ArwedMett, see @Mark's comment above and edited answer, it now complies with you request. Thank's to Mark `:D`

Comment: Actually that's really cool, but is kind of useless if you want to do something like this:

Comment: \tree{
    \tree{
        something
    }
}

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos see my last comments

Comment: @ArwedMett, to format text like code enclose the text between ``, then it looks like this: `<text>`. You're also able to edit comments and questions by clicking **edit** to avoid long discussions in the website. Last but not least: if you want to make several **different** tree structures in your document, you might as well use the tikz normal notation. Macros are supposed to do **repetition** so they are usually not very flexible... As far as I can see, your *current* question is answered.

Answer (score 5):

With `forest` is easy to draw this tree distribution. The package compute all distances.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [tree, for tree={draw, no edge}
        [child 1]
        [child 2]
        [child 3]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [tree, for tree={draw, no edge}
        [child 1]
        [child 2]
        [child 3]
        [child 4]
        [child 5]
        [child 6]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

Diving into `forest` documentation previous examples can be automatically created with a command like:

```
\newcommand{\mytree}[3]{
    \begin{forest}
        before typesetting nodes={for descendants={content=#3, draw, no edge}}
        [#1 , draw, repeat={#2}{append={[]}}]
    \end{forest}}
```

First parameter is top node contents, second is the number of children and the third is children contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\newcommand{\mytree}[3]{
    \begin{forest}
        before typesetting nodes={for descendants={content=#3, draw, no edge}}
        [#1 , draw, repeat={#2}{append={[]}}]
    \end{forest}}


\begin{document}
\centering
\mytree{tree}{5}{child}\\[1cm]

\mytree{A}{3}{B}\\[1cm]

\mytree{\emph{tree}}{10}{$x$}

\end{document}
```

[image]